# What is causing my browsers to require multiple clicks?

Tags: bug, web-browser, click

As of about a few weeks ago, I'm finding that I need to often (not always) click on links multiple times before they activate in my web browsers.

The details:

- it happens in both Chrome and Safari
- sometimes it's two clicks, sometimes 3, sometimes more
- it's not just web content, but the browser UI as well (switching tabs, closing tabs, etc)
- It's not all the time. Sometimes things work on first click, sometimes they don't. It seems pretty random.
- other software doesn't seem affected
- I haven't added any new plugins to the browsers.

Any theories as to what is going on? Googling seems to indicate that this happened may years ago due to a Flash plugin issue, but I don't have any flash plugins anymore. Anyone else having this issue? Known problem with a recent OSX update?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browsers as well as your computer? This seems more like a UI lag than a outright bug.

Comment: It's not a UI lag that I can tell (that's an issue at times too) But this has been happening even after a fresh reboot.

Comment: Have you checked your mouse/trackpad settings?

Comment: @IronCraftMan no, though not sure what I'd check there. It's a problem only with the two web browsers mentioned. All my other apps seem OK.